# MySQLdb within python2.5 virtualenv

Tags: python, mysql, virtualenv

I have a Fedora 11 box with MySQL server.  Fedora 11 uses python 2.6 internally and python 2.6 is automatically installed on the box.  I have created a python virtual-env for version 2.5.5, so that I can run turbogears 1.x application.  I have MySQLdb rpm installed on the box (and it works fine with python 2.6).

When I import MySQLdb from within python version 2.6 it imports is successfully.  When I import MySQLdb from within the python 2.5.5 virtual-env the import fails (because I have installed virtual-env with --no-site-packages).  So, I have to install MySQLdb python as a local package (local to virtual-env).

'easy_install MySQL-python' within the virtual env fails.  It downloads the MySQL-python-1.2.3.c1.tar.gz/download, but the 'python setup.py build' fails with  error.  The same problem occurs when building the MySQL outside of virtual-env.

Is the 'python setup.py build' for MySQL-python trying to link to a library (and am I missing some library)?  Or is the downloaded code missing some header files (unlikely)?

Thanks.

---

S.Mark,

If I were to install MySQL header files, would they mess with the existing rpms?

[Sorry, for being redundant.  In essence, MySQL is functional on the machine, MySQL-python is functional for python 2.6, but MySQL-python is not functional from virtualenv for python 2.5.5.]

Thank you for trying to help.

```
# rpm -qa | grep -i mysql
MySQL-python-1.2.3-0.4.c1.fc11.x86_64  
perl-DBD-MySQL-4.010-1.fc11.x86_64  
mysql-libs-5.1.42-7.fc11.x86_64  
mysql-5.1.42-7.fc11.x86_64  
php-mysql-5.2.12-1.fc11.x86_64  
mysql-server-5.1.42-7.fc11.x86_64
```

Comment: Are we supposed to guess *what* error?

Comment: Without the error its impossible to guess what might have gone wrong

Answer (score 6):

```
_mysql.c:36:23: error: my_config.h: No such file or directory
_mysql.c:38:19: error: mysql.h: No such file or directory
_mysql.c:39:26: error: mysqld_error.h: No such file or directory
_mysql.c:40:20: error: errmsg.h: No such file or directory
```

Please install MySQL header files, probably [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=383269#mirrors)

Comment: Just to mention for the others that might end up here too.

Answer (score 1):

Works!  Thanks for all your help.

I installed mysql-devel package (yum install mysql-devel) on the box.

Then did easy_install MySQL-python from within virtual-env (python 2.5.5), and the compilation/installation was successful (with some warnings).

Thanks.

Comment: glad it worked. you should give those that helped you some +1 karma, it's the stackoverflow way. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention for the others that might end up here too,

I solved this error in installing mysql-devel

```
$ yum install mysql-devel.x86_64
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In case it does not work even after installing mysql-devel package, check the contents of "/usr/include/mysql".

If is empty then its possible that mysql-devel has installed the header files at some pther place, run following command to find

> find /usr/include/ -maxdepth 1 -name mysql*

If found, create a symlink like following to fix the problem.

> ln -s /usr/include/mysql51 /usr/include/mysql