# cannot install MySQLdb on virtualenv (Mac 10.13)

Tags: python, mysql

I'm new to using virtualenv and I'm having trouble installing MySQLdb on my virtualenv.

I'm currently using Python 2.7 and here is what my current virtualenv looks like

```
click==6.7
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.0
MySQL-python==1.2.5
mysqlclient==1.3.12
SQLAlchemy==1.2.8
Werkzeug==0.14.1
```

I first saw this error when I was coding on my normal machine (Mac 10.13), and when I initially tried to install MySQLdb, I got this error.

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-rxnRuR/MySQL-python/
```

I was able to fix it by using the second solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448429/how-to-install-mysqldb-python-data-access-library-to-mysql-on-mac-os-x)

However, when I start up my **virtual environment** and attempt to install MySQLdb I get the same error code as above, but I do not have the same directories that are provided in the solution I originally found.

I've tried to piece together solutions from the follow questions trying to see if there is a solution for installing MySQLdb in virtualenv
[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954884/virtualenv-pip-mysqldb-mac-os-x-python), [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304539/mysqldb-within-python2-5-virtualenv), [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631299/error-when-installing-mysql-python-with-pip-install-in-osx-virtualenv), but none of them seem to work

I was hoping someone might be able to explain what's going on so that I work with MySQLdb in a virtual environment.

Commands tried:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools
brew install mysql
brew install mysql-python

brew uninstall mysql
brew install mysql-connector-c
brew unlink mysql-connector-c
brew install mysql
pip install mysql-python
```

UPDATE: This seems to be a known issue and is in a [Github thread](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/issues/169) I ended up solving the above error code using the solution found [here](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/pull/143), but now when I start up Python and I try to import MySQLdb, I get the following error code

```
Reason: image not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27264574/import-psycopg2-library-not-loaded-libssl-1-0-0-dylib) solved the problem, below is the command I used to make it work.

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/anaconda2/lib/:$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
```

A few notes however...

- I had to run this command WITHIN my virtual environment for it to work, not my global environment
- I was told this is a problem with Anaconda managing my packages and my virtual environment variables not being able to find the correct paths
- You'll notice that my folder is "~/anaconda2/..." check to see where your lib files are installed on your global environment and make sure you adjust the directory name accordingly
- Also I was suggested to keep this command in an initialization file for my virtual environment, that way whenever my virtual environment loads, this command is already executed

Answer (score 0):

Try  this :

1. **brew uninstall mysql-connector-c**
2. **brew install mysql**
3. **invoke "mysql_config --libs" and confirm its output include correct library options: "-L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.20/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto"**
4. **export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib && pip install mysqlclient**

I hope this helps

Comment: I think I tried it in some form or another before, but I just tried it again right now just in case, Unfortunately it still gives me the same error code :( thanks though

Comment: I changed my answer
I hope that helps :)

Comment: Yep! I recently made it that far. I posted an update and one of the solutions given was the one you wrote down. Now I'm trying to **import MySQLdb** within python and I get the error posted in my update. If you have any info please let me know!

Comment: try to reinstall it, This might help <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182294/installing-mysql-python-on-mac-os-x>